# How to connect to the spark master remotely using the spark shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

./dse spark --master spark://*sparkMasterIp*:port --name "testConnection" --conf "spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandraHost1, cassandraHost2" --conf spark.app.name=TryShell --conf spark.broadcast.port=54001

Comment: Is the code not working?  How?

Comment: where have you provided --class and application jar in the command ?